# Set the height of the entire editor in a tinymce-vue component

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

Im using this component https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue and I want to set the height of the entire editor to `500 px`.

```
<editor api-key="myapikey" :init="{plugins: 'wordcount,'"></editor>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figure it out, just need to add the `height` property to the `:init` prop, like this:

```
<editor api-key="myapikey" :init="{plugins: 'wordcount',height: 500}"></editor>
```